# List of my unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, search

In the profile, each user has access to several classifications of his own questions : according to "newest", "reputation", "activity" etc
 Is there a way I can access the list of all my unanswered questions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This search should do:

> [`user:XXXX is:question hasaccepted:0`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3A0)

If you want your user number `me` could be used instead of the actual number.

Comment: Is there any general rule on how to produce such "search codes"? This is quite useful!

Comment: Peter, if you run an empty search you will reach a page explaining the search options. Plus there's always google...

Comment: Thanks. I would have never thought of running an empty search.